# How to modify a model to be cyclic?

Tags: linear-programming, constraint, scheduling

I have the following question. I have the following physician problem with the indices $I$ (doctor), $T$ (days) and $J$ (shifts). $x_{itj}$ is the decision variable, $d_{tj}$ is the demand and $g$ is a fixed number. The model is as follows.
\begin{align}
&\min \sum_{i,t,j}^{}x_{i(\mod (t-1,14)+1)j}\cdot c_j\\
&\sum_{i}^{}x_{i(\mod (t-1,14)+1)j}\ge d_{tj} &&\forall t\in T, j\in J\\\
&\sum_{j}^{}x_{i(\mod (t-1,14)+1)j}\le1 &&\forall i\in I, t\in T\\\
&x_{i(\mod (t-1,14)+1)3}+x_{i(\mod (t,14)+1)1}\le 1 &&\forall I \in I, t\in \{1,\ldots,T-1\}\\\
&\sum_{l=t}^{t+g}\sum_{j}^{}x_{i(\mod (l-1,14)+1)j}\le g &&\forall i\in I, j\in J\\
&x_{i(\mod (t-1,14)+1)j}+x_{i(\mod (t,14)+1)j}+s_{i(t+1)}\le 2&& \forall i\in I,k\in K,t\in\{1,\ldots,T-1\}\\
&x_{i(\mod (t-1,14)+1)j}+\sum_{k\neq j}^{}x_{i(\mod (t,14)+1)k}\le1+s_{i(t+1)}&& \forall i\in I,k\in K,t\in\{1,\ldots,T-1\}\
\end{align}

Now to my question. I currently have 28 days as the planning period. However, I would now like to create cyclical plans, so that after 28 days it starts again from the beginning. How do I have to extend/modify my model, especially with regard to linking the days with $t+1$ etc.? And how can I introduce a parameter that controls the number of cycles?

EDIT: I updated the model, as suggested by @RobPratt. Now, i have a a 28 planing horizon, with two cycles a 14 days. Whenever i try to solve this model, i only get solutions for 14 days, regarding $x_{itj}$. Why is that?

Comment: *"And how can I introduce a parameter that controls the number of cycles?"* << If it's truly periodic, why does the number of periods matter? Just pretend it's really a circular cycle with no beginning and no end.

Comment: The use of $\mod$ means that the $t$ index of $x$ is always in $\{1,\dots,14\}$. To recover the schedule for the second $14$-day cycle, just copy the solution from the first cycle. Also, you still mistakenly have both $\sum_j$ and $j\in J$ in the $\le g$ constraint.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to enforce that $x_{i,t,j}=x_{i,t+28,j}$, you can explicitly impose that constraint and let the presolver do the substitution.

Or omit the explicit constraints and do the substitution yourself by replacing $t$ with $\mod(t,28)$ for each $x_{i,t,j}$ variable (assuming $t$ starts at $0$).  It looks like your $t$ starts at $1$, so you can instead replace $t$ with $\mod(t-1,28)+1$ for each $x_{i,t,j}$ variable.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean instead of writing $x_{it3}+x_{i(t+1)1}\le 1$ with $x_{i(\mod(t-1,28)+1)3}+x_{i(\mod(t-1,28)+2)1}\le1$ f.e?

Comment: Almost. The first one is correct. The second one should instead be $x_{i,\mod(t+1-1,28)+1,1}$.

Comment: Thanks. And If I apply that logic to all constraints i can model the cyclic behaviour. That would ensure that the third constraint f.e. also must be fullfilled for $t=28$ in cycle 1 and $t=1$ in cycle 2, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Perfect. And 1) how can I add a parameter that controls the number of cycles? 2) How do I deal with the end of the last cycle, how do I need to modify my constraints?

Comment: The number of cycles is implicit in the definition of $T$.

Comment: Ah I get it now. So by making sure the beginning of each "cycle" is the same. The same schedule for each cycle will result (without rotation), meaning the schedule for all physicans will be the same in period 1-28, as well as 29-56?

Comment: Yes, the schedule will be the same in every 28-day cycle, even though the demand $d_{tj}$ can differ across cycles.

Comment: Thank you. One last question, then that's really it. Do I have to modify 
$T$ somehow so that there are no problems with the last period of the final cycle? Or how do I handle this? edit: since I am using Gurobi, and modulo is not supported, how can I implement it another way?

Comment: The set $T$ is given as part of the input. If you want to avoid $\mod$, you can use the explicit constraints. Also, your last constraint is wrong because it uses $j$ in two different ways. I suspect that you don’t want $j\in J$ there.

Comment: Assuming I have more variables such as $y_{it}$ or $r_{tj}$. Do I need to replace $t$ in every variable it appears or only in $x_{itj}$?

Comment: Yes, if you want those variables to be the same in every cycle.

Comment: I replaced $t$ with your-$\mod$ notation, but now the solver only solves the model and the respective $x_{itj}$ values for 14 days, even though I have $T=28$. Why could that be?

Comment: I recommend editing your answer to show what you tried.

Comment: A added new information...